# curl: How to fix "Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page"

Tags: javascript, html, curl

When I am using `curl` in order to retrieve a html page, I face with the following message:

`Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page`.

I am not sure how to handle this, hence I can open the same page on my web-browser.

**[Q]** How could I fix this in order retrieve html-page's information only using terminal?

```
$ curl http://bsod.pw/

<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
     <script>
       function onSubmit(token) {
         document.getElementById("recaptcha-form").submit();
       }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="recaptcha-loading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;  z-index: 30001; opacity: 0.8;">
<p style="position: absolute; color: White; top: 30%; left: 40%;">
<img src="https://250410.selcdn.ru/antiddos/lg.rotating-balls-spinner.gif">
</p>
</div>
  <center><noscript><h1 style="text-align:center;color:red;"><strong>Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</strong></h1></noscript>
    <form id='recaptcha-form' action="/captcha" method="POST">
      <button id='submitbutton' style="visibility:hidden;" class="g-recaptcha" data-badge=bottomright data-sitekey="6LcigjgUAAAAACyu9edrmWKmIce8h0kIFQz7iyRo" data-callback='onSubmit'></button>
        <script>
        window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('submitbutton').click();
                }
        </script>
      <br/>
    </form>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you do `inspect element` on the site(http://bsod.pw/) you can see that more detailed html code.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: [Wget does not have support for executing Javascript.](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/faq.html#Does_Wget_understand_JavaScript.3F)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "error". You make a GET request using curl. It returns you some HTML. The HTML happens to contain mostly links to JavaScript code that your browser is supposed to load and to execute. Your browser (with JS activated) could load the `.js` scripts and run them. Those scripts would generate some neat web page. If you don't load the linked scripts, and do not execute them, then you don't get much out of the page. Consider using a proper headless browser instead (see example below).

Here is a small example that is supposed to demonstrate the point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Source code empty, page full!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fillThis">
      <p>Almost nothing there in the source code!</p>
      <p>... but inspect this div after JS is executed.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
      var fillThis = document.getElementById("fillThis");
      for (i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
        var child = document.createElement('p');
        child.innerHTML = "tons of content " + i;
        fillThis.appendChild(child);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just save this as "something.html", and open it in the browser. When you ask you browser to show page source, this is exactly what you will get. However, when you inspect the `div` by right-clicking on it, it will show a that it has >1000 child elements appended to it. Those are generated by JS in your browser, they do not come from the server in form of HTML.

**Edit**

I tried to access the page using PhantomJS, it almost worked. Here is what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<HereDoc > /tmp/phantomjsScript.js
  var page = require('webpage').create();
  page.open('http://example.com', function(status) {
    if(status === "success") {
      console.log(page.frameContent);
    }
    phantom.exit();
  });
HereDoc

phantomjs /tmp/phantomjsScript.js
```

This is a bash script that generates a helper script in `/tmp`, which is then executed by `phantomjs`. PhantomJS loads the website, and also executes the JavaScript. Unfortunately, the website that you've linked to is protected by a captcha-mechanism, and is not directly accessible, so the above example uses `example.com` instead. If you can somehow work around the captcha, you probably can use a similar script to load the HTML, run the JS, and then dump the rendered DOM to the console.

Comment: Site's original output is different. It gives the same output I showed on my question. But if you do inspect element, you can see much more code. @Dez

Comment: Is there any headless browser you recommend? @Andrey Tyukin

Comment: (...tinkering on a phantomjs solution. You might want to take look at PhantomJS documentation...)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestion to handle reCAPTCHA? or could I ask it under different question? @Andrey Tyukin

Comment: You probably should. "Why does curl not give me some html" is quite different from "How do I recaptcha with phantomjs". The question topic would drift way too far away. And I have no clue about recaptcha right at the moment anyway...

Answer (score -1):

Try running the code on chrome. Actually the error is due to captcha connection and the error says "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again."

Comment: I need to obtain result from terminal. @MukeshR.